# I blocked my access to my own drive on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

There is 2 account on my computer, mine which is administrator and and other which is a simple user.

I wanted to block access to some hard drive to this user and I ended up blocking it for everyone.

I right clicked on the drive, went into the security tab, selected the "user group" and check "denied" on every checkboks.

How can I regain access to those drives?

[image: what I did]

my guess is that my administrator account is also part of the user group and thus is being block.
I cannot access the security tab anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a administrator command line, the following should help:

```
C:\>takeown /f F: /r /d y
C:\>icacls F: /grant administrators:F /t
```

takeown: /r is for recursive, /d y is to answer all questions with "yes"

icacls: :F is for full access, /t is for recursive